# Passing input from html to python and back

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask, cgi

I need to make a webpage for an assignment, it doesn't have to be uploaded to the web, I am just using a local .html file.
I did some reading up and came up with the following html and python:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            CV - Rogier
        </title>
    </head
    <body>
        <h3>
            Study
        </h3>
        <p>
            At my study we learn Python.<br>
            This is a sall example:<br>
            <form action="/cgi-bin/cvpython.py" method="get">
                First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name">  <br />
                Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name" />
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Python:

```
import cgi
import cgitb #found this but isn't used?

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

first_name = form.getvalue('first_name').capitalize()
last_name  = form.getvalue('last_name').capitalize()

print ("Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n")
print ("<html>")
print ("<head>")
print ("<title>Hello - Second CGI Program</title>")
print ("</head>")
print ("<body>")
print ("<h2>Your name is {}. {} {}</h2>".format(last_name, first_name, last_name))
print ("</body>")
print ("</html>")
```

However this just gives the prints as text and not as a proper html file with the 1 line that I want.

Comment: In python, newline is just `\n`, not `\r\n`.

Comment: What browser do you use?

Comment: `Content-Type: text/html`

Comment: Ah yes, I copied that line but will try with just `/n`. I use chrome

Comment: @Peter Wood is that supposed to fix the problem? (because it doesn't)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you have a web server like apache setup this is running on? 
If you don't I'm not sure this will work so you may want to have a look at [Mamp](https://www.mamp.info/en/) To allow it to execute your python script you will also need to edit the `httpd.conf` file

From:

```
<Directory />
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

To:

```
  <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
  Options +ExecCGI
  AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py
  Order allow,vdeny
  Allow from all
  </Directory>
```

**Alternatively**

If you simply want to make an actual HTML file without setting up a server a very basic but crude way of doing this would be to simply write everything to a HTML file you create like:

```
fo.write("Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n")
fo.write("<html>")
fo.write("<head>")
fo.write("<title>Hello - Second CGI Program</title>")
fo.write("</head>")
fo.write("<body>")
fo.write("<h2>Your name is {}. {} {}</h2>".format("last_name", "first_name", "last_name"))

fo.write("</body>")
fo.write("</html>")

fo.close()
```

Which will create a HTML document called `yourfile.html` in the same directory as your python project.

I don't recommend doing this, but I realise since it's an assignment you may not have the choice to use libraries. In case you, are a more elegant way would be to use something like [yattag](http://www.yattag.org/) which will make it much more maintainable.

To copy the Hello World example from their website.

```
from yattag import Doc

doc, tag, text = Doc().tagtext()

with tag('h1'):
    text('Hello world!')

print(doc.getvalue())
```

**Update:**

Another alternative if you don't have a local web server setup is to use [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)  as your web server.
You'll need to structure your project like:

```
    /yourapp  
    basic_example.py  
    /static/  
        /test.css
    /templates/  
        /test.html
```

Python:

```
__author__ = 'kai'

from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('test.html')

@app.route('/hello', methods=['POST'])
def hello():
    first_name = request.form['first_name']
    last_name = request.form['last_name']
    return 'Hello %s %s have fun learning python <br/> <a href="/">Back Home</a>' % (first_name, last_name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host = '0.0.0.0', port = 3000)
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/test.css">
        <title>
            CV - Rogier
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>
            Study
        </h3>
        <p>
            At my study we learn Python.<br>
            This is a sall example:<br>
            <form action="/hello" method="post">
                First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name">  <br />
                Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name" />
                <input type="submit" name= "form" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS (If you want to style your form?)

```
p {
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 20px;
}
h2 {
    color: navy;
    margin-left: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Made a basic example based on your question [here](https://github.com/spik3r/simpleFlaskForm)
Hopefully this helps get you on the right track, good luck.

Comment: I don't know what I want, I just tried to make it work using this site https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.html
How would I call/open that new html file from my main one?

Comment: Do you have the python script setup on a web server like apache? What is the aim? Do you just want to have python create a web page?

Comment: No, I need to make an html page, server is not required. I want to be able to enter a name (or anything) on the html page, have that sent to a python script, which does something with it, and relayed back to the browser (be it the same tab or a new tab)

Comment: (but I can use a web server if I want, and I'll try to with your answer)

Answer (score 0):

Change the below in apache/conf/httpd.conf file:

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/cgi-bin"> 
    AllowOverride All
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

To:

```
  <Directory "C:/xampp/cgi-bin">
  Options ExecCGI
  AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  </Directory>
```

otherwise run html form also using python script:(No need to change above http.conf file)

```
#!C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Python.exe

print("Content-type:text/html \r\n\r\n")
print('<html>')
print('<body>')
print('<form action="/cgi-bin/hello_get.py">')
print('First Name:<input type = "text" name = "first_name"><br/>')
print('Last Name:<input type = "text" name = "last_name" />')
print('<input type = "submit" value = "submit">')
print('</form>')
print('</body>')
print('</html>')`
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to both HTML and Python, but as far as I know HTML doesn't have to be indented. This means that you can pass a lot of HTML code in one python print.
You can actually print a whole HTML code in one line.

I'm printing lists into html tables with for loops. 
The HTML code is not nice, but it's working.
*I guess you only need them to be temporary, as I do.*

Cheers!

Comment: You're right that indentation doesn't matter in html. And that you can do it all in one line. But indentation or non-indentation of the html wasn't the problem. It was webserver setup (see the accepted answer).

Comment: Sorry, I know, I just wanted to add it, because was a saw him writing it line by line, and that's painful to do. But I can't comment yet.

Comment: A comment would be better, you're right. But not having enough points to comment yet is a very valid reason, of course :-) Welcome here at stackoverflow in any case! After a while, you'll have the points you need.

Answer (score 0):

firstly check browser url like that it looks like
file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/cgi_python/form.html

that means your code is correct and no error
 but output show as a python script  code 
because  "code work in console not in browser"

i.e mean
 you directly open a file  in htdocs folder 
and click filename.html and execute then output from in text format 
For open a browser

Solution is

1. open browser type in url
2. localhost/filepath
   eg. http://localhost/cgi_python/form.html
   then get the answer