# Get input from user in html and convert to python list

Tags: html, python-3.x, list, input

I want to code a website which gets an input and then put's it into a python list.

Html:

```
<input type="text" name="searchbox">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

I just want to get the input from the user and then append it to a list in python.

Comment: There's a different question related to html and python that may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43677564/passing-input-from-html-to-python-and-back#43678106